# Mixed array with json - parsing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am doing a youtube api call, and I get back a `var result = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);` which looks like  :

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
    "pageInfo": {
            "totalResults": 1000000,
            "resultsPerPage": 5
        },
    "items": [
        {
            "id": {
                "kind": "youtube#video",
                "videoId": "DEne4AoX_RU"
            },
            "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
            "snippet": {
                "publishedAt": "2012-11-22T22:36:15.000Z",
                "thumbnails": {
                    "default": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DEne4AoX_RU/default.jpg"
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DEne4AoX_RU/mqdefault.jpg"
                    },
                    "high": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DEne4AoX_RU/hqdefault.jpg"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": {...}
```

The full object response returns correctly in my console but I want to retrieve thumbnails url and display it as an li-tagged html list
So I tried first to fetch in a list all the snippet entries :

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(result);
$.each(obj, function() {
    output += this.snippet + + "<br/>";
});
console.log(output);
```

But I have an message in my console : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`. What am I missing ? Btw, I don't understand why there are still brackets in the json stringified `result` (if someone could advise some good doc to understand how to parse JSON, would be great:))

Comment: Why do you stringify the response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be looping over `items`:

```
$.each(obj.items, function() {
    output += this.snippet ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What you receive is JSON, you shouldn't stringify it.

Remove this line

```
var result = JSON.stringify(response, '', 2);
```

and simply do

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(response);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you want to iterate over `items`,
2. `snippet` is an object literal,
3. `+ +` is not valid javascript.